# Python: Object-oriented Programming (getting age of Artist)

Tags: python

Question: Create an age method in the Artist class, which would return the age of the artist as of 'today'. (get_date_today() already predefined) For example: Artist("Hayley Williams", (1988, 12, 27)).age()  will return 24. It should work for other examples as well, not just this.

My attempt:

```
def get_date_today():
    return (2013, 10, 30)

class Artist(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dob):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_dob(self):
        return self.dob

    def age(self):
        return ((get_date_today())) - get_dob(self))/365
```

However i realise i can't just subtract tuples. Anyone has any idea how to improve this solution?

Comment: You cant substract date directly, you have to convert it into a `datetime` object, then you can substract it and get the difference or you can simply substract the years in tuples.

Comment: yes this is very time consuming to do without using `datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use tuples, you just need to unpack them into the datetime object.  Also when you call a local method you need to do `self.method` not `method(self)`.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date_today():
    return (2013, 10, 30)

dt = datetime(*get_date_today())

class Artist(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dob):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_dob(self):
        return self.dob

    def age(self):
        return (datetime(*get_date_today()) - datetime(*self.get_dob())).days/365

justin = Artist('JB', (1996, 8 ,28))
print(justin.age())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you review the documentation for [DateTime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__) they show an example similar to this.